# construct a correct tabular

Tags: graphics, tabularx

I'm trying to create a tabular with 2 column (1 for text and 1 for an image with a caption).
And now, i've got an anarchist tabular, where my first column is ok but in the second one, image aren't centered, they are out of the box, (cf. the picture).

Here is the code :

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.7cm}}
        Monochromatique & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Image/spectre_mono.png}\\
        \hline
        Spectre discret & \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{Image/Spectre_discret.jpg}\\[2cm]
        \hline
         Spectre continu & \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{Image/Spectre_lampe_halogene.jpg}\\
        \hline
        Spectre d'absorption & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Image/Abs.jpg}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx} \normalfont
\end{table}
```

And here is the result :
[image]

Any idea ?

*I create the tabular with this template :*

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163873/horizontal-and-vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cell

Comment: You shouldn't use `tabularx` with no `X` column.

Comment: why shouldn't I ?

Comment: What's the use? What you may obtain is horizontal rules longer than the tabular contents width (I doubt that `3cm +3.7cm +4\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth` be equal to `\textwidth` –  unless you print on A6 paper).

Comment: Ohh ok, it's adapting :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest also use `adjustbox` but scaling the images to respect the width of the X column using only `width=\linewidth`. This way  is more appealing as all the images have exactly the same width and avoid center the images(note that I use also `height`,but only to simulate the dimensions of wide spectral images. You should not use that for the true images.).

Note also that the relative length of `\linewidth` is the width of the column, but it does not include the horizontal  padding  of`\tabcolsep` whereas by default there are not a similar vertical padding. Moreover, in this case I guess that you a left-top-bottom image margin, but not a right margin. The second table solve this problem with a `\fbox{}`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\tabcolsep0pt
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}|X}
        Monochromatique & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image}\\\hline
        Spectre discret & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=\linewidth,,height=2cm]{example-image}\\\hline
        Spectre continue & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}\\\hline
        Spectre d'absorption & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}\\\hline        
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\tabcolsep0pt\fboxrule0pt\fboxsep1em
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm}|X}
        Monochromatique &\fbox{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-1em,height=1cm]{example-image}}\\\hline
        Spectre discret & \fbox{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-1em,height=2cm]{example-image}}\\\hline
        Spectre continue & \fbox{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-1em]{example-image-1x1}}\\\hline
        Spectre d'absorption & \fbox{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=\dimexpr\linewidth-1em]{example-image-16x9}}\\\hline        
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are more satisfied with the following solution using `valign=c` from the `adjustbox` package in combination with `cellspace`. I have also replaced the `tabularx` with a regular `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove demo option in actual document
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{cellspace} % For added shite space above and below image
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{\tabcolsep}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\tabcolsep}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % For valign option
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|Sl}
        Monochromatique & \includegraphics[scale=0.25, valign=c]{Image/spectre_mono.png}\\
        \hline
        Spectre discret & \includegraphics[scale=0.55, valign=c]{Image/Spectre_discret.jpg}\\
        \hline
         Spectre continu & \includegraphics[scale=0.35, valign=c]{Image/Spectre_lampe_halogene.jpg}\\
        \hline
        Spectre d'absorption & \includegraphics[scale=0.25, valign=c]{Image/Abs.jpg}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it almost works ^^,
Indeed, the third figure is note the same, it's in the case, but not centered...
And i've tried the `\centering`, It doesn't work...

Comment: To horizonally center the figures inside of the table cells, replace `Sl` with `Sc`.